# Generate a sequence in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to take an integer from the user, and generate a sequence of five numbers starting with the given integer, and multiplying each previous number by four, using iteration. E.g., if I enter `2` then the list should be `[2, 8, 32, 128, 512]`.

```
n = gets
i = 0
while i < 4
  n = n * 4
  p n
  i = i + 1
end
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Yes, but the troube Im having is to iterate the value for the sequence. I keep getting it as [2,2,2,2,2]

Comment: At the start of your block, do value ||= gets, then put the new variable 'value' into the array. The same iteration, multiply the variable 'value' by 4 and move onto the next one. The next iteration, the first part, ||= will do nothing (as the variable 'value' already exists), it will put the multiplied value into the array, and continue as many times as you tell it to

Comment: Ive put up what I had did, I would want to store those values in a an array how would that be possible then ?

Comment: n=2;
i=0;
a=Array.new;
while (i<4)
  n=n*4;
  a.push n;
  i=i+1;
end
 p a;

Comment: `4.times.reduce([gets.chomp.to_i]) { |memo| memo + [memo[-1] * 4] }`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking to create an array of numbers to use later or just want to iterate.  In the following you can replace puts memo with whatever you want, memo will contain the value you are looking for each pass.

```
s = 2 
(s...(s+5)).reduce(s) do |memo, i| 
    puts memo
    memo = memo * 4 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
(5 - 1).times.with_object([gets.to_i]){|i, a| a.push(a.last * 4)}
```

Input:

```
2
```

Return value:

```
[2, 8, 32, 128, 512]
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish what you are describing. You already have some implementations in the comments and in the other answer by @Abhimanyu.

> the trouble I'm having is to iterate the value for the sequence. I keep getting it as [2,2,2,2,2]

Your code example won't work because [`Kernel#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) doesn't return a number, but a `String` followed by a newline character (because it uses a default separator, from the global variable `$/`, which happens to be `"\n"`):

```
[1] pry(main)> gets
2
=> "2\n"
[2] pry(main)> gets.class
2
=> String
```

To fix your snippet you'll need to add `.chomp.to_i` to remove the newline and to convert it to an integer:

```
def generate_sequence
  n = gets.chomp.to_i
  i = 0
  while i < 4
    n = n * 4
    p n
    i = i + 1
  end
end
```